# This site can’t provide a secure connection when deploying node app on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, node.js

i have simple nodejs app running on ec2 instance, when tried to access the app from browser using `"ec2-18-223-0-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4545 refused to connect."`
 it give me

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
```

when trying to curl it from VM using `curl http://localhost:4545` it works correctly, however when trying `curl http://127.0.0.1:4545` it give me this output

```
Found. Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:4545/
```

here's my security rules for the instance, i'm allowing all ip's to access the instance

[image]

also checking if the app is running at port 4545

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :4545
tcp6       0      0 :::4545                 :::*                    LISTEN      1942/node
```

I've been stuck into this issue from yesterday without any luck, neither know what's the cause, i've tried several solutions, non works :/

Comment: First guess is this has something to do with the application you’re running and not ec2. I think you should re-ask the question providing some details about  the node app, including configuration or part of the app code.

Comment: I tried to reach your app and could not. It just timed out. Are you sure it is allowed in the firewall?

Comment: @MichaelHampton how can i achieve that?

Comment: @JeffSnider will update the question with my service.js file

Comment: Actually just figured it out, there was a middleware that redirecting all http to https, commented that line and it worked, my bad  , thanks guys ur comments helped me :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually just figured it out, there was a middleware in the node app that redirecting all http to https, commented that line and it worked, my bad